# Can't save object pushed to array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi i have strange issue with mongoose.

```
Group.findById(req.params.group_id, function(err, group){
        User.findOne(req.body, function(err, user){
            group.users.push(user);
            user.groups.push(group);
            group.save();
            user.save();
            res.json({group: group, user: user});
            return true;    
        });
    });
```

I try to create double way relation between user and group. User is properly pushed to the group.users array and saved perfectly. The issue appear when i try to save group in user.groups array. There is no action on mongo side until i will try to run this action again. Old element now is saved properly, and new one is still don't saved. On express side everything seems to be fine, and objects that are returned to the front end are also valid.

Here you have visualization of my problem

```
> Group    User     group.users in database  user.groups in database
> group1   user1       [user1]                   []       
> group2   user2      [user1, user2]            [group1]
> group3   user3    [user1, user2, user3]     [group1, group2]
```

I hope you understand where is the key of the issue.

Do you have any advice of how to fix that problem?

Comment: have you checked the suggested answer yet?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't working on that project yesterday. Everything works fine now, thanks for your help. It is perfect.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just remember to accept the answer for anyone else who looking for a solution to a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the async operation of `save` so you would need to nest them like so (assuming you are using refs for the array subdocuments):

```
Group.findById(req.params.group_id, function(err, group){
  User.findOne(req.body, function(err, user){
    group.users.push(user);
    group.save(function (err, group) {
      user.groups.push(group);
      user.save(function (err, group) {
        res.json({group: group, user: user});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I would also look into using a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to speed up this process since the two queries to find a group and a user aren't dependent on each other.